# How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (console)

Tags: java, arrays

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at com.PenguinGaming.Player.User(Player.java:47)
at com.PenguinGaming.Game.main(Game.java:18)
```

Not sure how to prevent the crash after 6. I would like it to say that that position is not available to go to. I tried

```
if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[1])){
            //Go north
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY+1]);
            if(playerY > 6){
                playerY -=1;
                System.out.println("You can not move in that direction");
            }
            playerY += 1;
        }
```

I have only worked with this problem once in a GUI and that was following a video and how we did it was destroyed the object once it reached. In this case I don't want to destroy it but, say it can't go any further. I think the problem is in my loop it adds one then checks so it goes above and crashes. To prevent this I would probably need to check before but not sure how.

### Player.java

```
package com.PenguinGaming;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

public void User(){

    Commands commands = new Commands();
    Map map = new Map();

    int Maxlife = 25;
    int life = 25;
    int turns = 0;

    //Starting player location
    int playerX = 4;
    int playerY = 4;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = null;


    while(life > 1){

        System.out.println("Player life: " + life + "/" + Maxlife);
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        input = input.toLowerCase();

        life -= 1;

        for(int i = 0; i == 30; i++){
            turns++;
            if(turns == 30){
                Maxlife += 5;
            }
        }

        if (input.equals(commands.commandlist()[0])) {
        // give description for player location
        System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY]);
        }

        if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[1])){
            //Go north
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY+1]);
            playerY += 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[2])){
            //Go east
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX+1][playerY]);
            playerX += 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[3])){
            //Go south
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY-1]);
            playerY -= 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[4])){
            //Go west
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX-1][playerY]);
            playerX -= 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[5])){
            //Terminate game
            break;
        }

        if(life <= 0){
            System.out.println("Looks like you have starved, better luck next game");
            break;
        }
        if(playerY > 6|| playerX > 6){
            System.out.println("You can not move in that direction");
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

### Game.java

```
package com.PenguinGaming;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Player player = new Player();
    Map map = new Map();

    boolean running = true;

    //Print starting location
    System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[4][4]);

    while(running){
    player.User();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check `playerY` before this line

```
System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY+1]);
```

I.e. :

```
    if(input.equals(commands.commandlist()[1])){
        if(playerY > 6){
            playerY -=1;
            System.out.println("You can not move in that direction");
        } else {
            //Go north
            System.out.println(map.MapLayout()[playerX][playerY+1]);
            playerY += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that mostly fixed it. Just had to change playerY >= 6 and then not subtract because if it is it needs to stay in it's current position at river.